# One Activity to Launch another?

Tags: java, android

Could anyone give an example of how one activity would launch another in android? Building my first android app thanks.

Thanks

Comment: what wrong with the documentation? you can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startAcitvity(intent);
```

You have further info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```